# Using React / Redux, doing a blog posts app, will the state be better with one `posts` property, or 2 separate properties?

Tags: reactjs, redux

Short question is: if it is React / Redux app, should the app state have two properties for `items` and `item`, and two reducers, or should the app state have one property `items` with two properties `all` and `item`, and 1 reducer?

---

Details: In a React / Redux blog post app, where the list of all posts can be viewed (a summary list), and the user can click on any line to see the full blog post with the full blog post content.

So in the main reducer:

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  posts: PostsReducer,
  form: formReducer
});
```

where the `posts` is initially:

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
    all: [],
    post: null
};
```

Note that for `all`, it has an array of post data, but has only the title and categories (such as sports and bicycle), and **does not have the blog content**, versus for `post`, it has only the data for one post, **but it does have the blog post's title, categories, and content (which may be 3000 words)**.

What are the pros and cons of using 2 separate properties in the main state instead? (like below)

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  all: PostsReducer,  // reducer for all
  post: PostReducer,  // reducer for one
  form: formReducer
});
```

Because there are two components (the list summary and the one showing one post), and two actions, my inclination was to use 2 separate reducers and 2 different properties in the main state, but I have seen an example of using 1 reducer and 1 property including both `all` and `post`. What are the pros and cons and should we actually use one way and not the other?

Comment: Which option do you prefer? Trust yourself - that one will be correct. If you will prefer another one later - you will refactor it.

Comment: hm... I don't know whether the reducer is supposed to group related items together... if so, then use 1 reducer. But if 2 different components... then 2 reducers, that also makes sense too